# php касячит при проверке float

Tags: float, php

Вопрос для знатоков php.
Есть код:

```
if($timeDiff > 24)
{
    $Tfail = $period - 0;
    var_dump($timeDiff); // float 24
}
else
{
    $Tfail = $period - $timeDiff;
}
```

`$timeDiff` вычисляется чуть ранее из нескольких интеграторов. Код периодически **заходит в первую ветку**. При  этом дамп переменной: **float 24**.
Вопрос: **почему?**

Comment: @artkil такой вариант действительно работает, хотя мне больше по душе  
    
    if(round($timeDiff,2) > 24)

Comment: а как вы добились `float(24)` ?

    php -r '$a=24;settype($a,"float");$a+=0.00001;$a-=0.00001; echo var_dump($a);echo var_dump($a);';php -v
    double(24)
    double(24)
    PHP 5.4.4-14 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2013 14:08:43) 
    Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
       with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans

Comment: @eicto хз. А вообще я не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: у меня в var_dump все float - double

Comment: @eicto узнаю, скажу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего это из-за внутреннего представления вещественных чисел в памяти. Сделайте в условии так: if ($timeDiff - 24 > 0.00001)

Comment: Вы бы хоть модуль разницы брали...

      if (abs($timeDiff - 24) > 0.00001)